# How to force multiple views to show the same model row

Tags: c++, qt

I have multiple QComboboxes sharing the same model. Usually they can independently select items in that model.
In some circumstances I wish to force those comboboxes to show the same model row, i.e. when one changes a selection, that should be reflected across the other combos.

This can be done via (a potential mess of) signals and slots, but I wonder if there is a way to do it more cleanly from the model end. I.e. force all views to show the same row.

A comment below points to sharing the selectionModel amongst the combos. I have done this by gathering my combos into a list and setting a model on them:

```
QList<QComboBox*> my_combos;
// .. then populate my_combos .. then
QComboBox *combo;
foreach(combo, my_combos)
    combo->setModel(&_my_model);
```

then

```
QItemSelectionModel *selectionmodel = my_combos.at(0)->view()->selectionModel();
  foreach(combo, my_combos)
  {
    if (combo == my_combos.at(0))
      continue;
    combo->view()->setSelectionModel(selectionmodel);
  }
```

Am I missing a step here?

Comment: The data model knows nothing of the views, and it's not its job to deal with it.

Comment: fair point - do you have a suggestion for a way to do this cleanly? As per the example Hayt provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selection is a red herring. `QComboBox` does not allow multiple item selection. What you're referring to as "selection" is the current index. It's easy to share it among combo boxes by connecting the `currentIndexChanged` signal to `setCurrentIndex`:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/combo-shared-select-39247471
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <array>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QApplication app{argc, argv};
    QStringListModel model;
    model.setStringList({ "foo", "bar", "baz "});

    QWidget ui;
    QHBoxLayout layout{&ui};
    std::array<QComboBox, 3> combos;
    // setIndices could be a method in a class
    auto setIndices = [&combos](int index) {
        for (auto & combo : combos)
            combo.setCurrentIndex(index);
    };
    for (auto & combo : combos) {
        using namespace std::placeholders;
        layout.addWidget(&combo);
        combo.setModel(&model);
        QObject::connect(&combo,
                         static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged),
                         setIndices);
    }
    ui.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Side note: You can hold the widgets by value. If their number is fixed at compile time, use `std::array`. Otherwise, you can use `std::list` with `emplace_back`. Signed, byValueGuy.

Comment: yeah that N^2 set of connections felt messy to me which is why I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: Nothing messy about it unless you have profiler results to prove otherwise, but yes, perhaps it's a premature pessimization. We can go from O(N^2) to O(N) in term of the number of connections.

Comment: I would connect them all to one slot of the upper widget and let this slot call all corresponding slots of the combo boxes. Looks a bit clearer an does the same. The part with being able to hold the object by value may be right but for consistency with how Qt works with objects I think using heap allocation is better here.

Comment: @Hayt OT here, but there is **nothing** in Qt that forces you to use heap allocation. It's a common misconception. I have modified the uic in my copy of Qt to emit `Ui::foo` classes with all objects held by value, for example. Works a treat and saves one layer of indirection when accessing widgets. Sure, one has to understand the scope of the values and ensure that children get destroyed before parents, but in practice it's not hard.

Comment: I prefer this (Hayts approach) too as I can block the signals of all the combos in the main slot before setting all the indexes of the combos.

Comment: I never said you have to and vector/array access by value is also way faster than by pointers. I was just mentioning it that Qt in itself uses this style. So one point for the use of heap-allocation would be style consistency. But yeah that's OT and both are perfectly valid (btw. when using heap-allocated `QObjects` using the Qt Containers is AFAIK more performant)

Comment: @Hayt That one slot is the lambda :) I've made it explicit.

Comment: @mike You don't have to block any signals. `QComboBox` behaves appropriately. This is working code. You don't need anything else.

Comment: Ah yeah. With different formatting it looks better though. But the result would be the same anyway

Comment: right I'll mark this as the answer since it is generally the approach I will take (no lambdas for me).

Comment: out of interest, why so bothered about using by value? I'm quite happy using pointers and always have been. Is there some inherent advantage? You say you save a layer of indirection, but then have to prefix widgets with & to pass them to functions expecting pointers.

Comment: The use of the address-taking operator is not a big hurdle. By storing things by value you avoid the premature pessimization of double indirection. Recall that a `QObject` internally is just a `QScopedPointer` to its PIMPL. It is 8/16 bytes. A `QWidget` is that and IIRC an additional 3 pointers - also very small. All `QObject`-deriving classes that are not widgets are the same size in Qt. Same with widgets. They are small values and storing each of them in a separate dynamically allocated block is unnecessary waste. Dynamically allocating them is an unnecessary additional work and typing.

Answer (score 2):

Check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#handling-selections-of-items

usually each view has it's own selection model, but you can have one view use the selection model of another view.

**Edit:** it seems like the `view` of `QComboBox` is only for the selection popup. You could additionally connect the selectionChanged/currentRowChanged signal of the selection model to each "setCurrentIndex".

Alternatively you can just let your parent class connect to each Signal of the comboboxes and then call the slot of each combobox in the signal handler of the parent class.

Comment: this looks like the answer (sharing the comboboxes->view()->selectionModel() )- but it doesn't seem to work for my qcomboboxes. I'll update the question with a code example

Comment: @mike OK I edited with some extension but it seems like it's not possible to just connect the Selection Models.

Comment: thanks Hayt. the second suggestion (connecting selectionChanged/currentRowChanged of the selection model to setCurrentIndex of the combos) won't work as the arguments don't match (I can't see either a setCurrentIndex which takes a QModelIndex nor selection/currentRowChanged which send an int). and the third selection is what I was hoping to avoid, maybe I'm being irrational but I don't like having to set so many connections up if I can help it.

Comment: yeah you need to use an extra slot or lambda to get `index.row()` and pass it to the combo box.